# Login via AsyncTask automatically fetching previously entered username,pwd

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am fetching username and password from MYSQL using php...code goes alright but when backpressed I am showing alert bar, Do you want to Logout? Then My LoginActivity comes in picture. Even if user enters wrong Username or password previous login data is fetched.
Here is my php code

```
<?php

    include("db.php");

    include("database.php");

    $uname=$_REQUEST['Username'];

    $upassword=$_REQUEST['Password'];

    if($upassword!='' && $uname!=''){

    $resultFac = SelectSingleRow("FacultyLogin","Password='$upassword' AND Username='$uname'","");

    if($resultFac['FacultyID']!=''){

        $facid= $resultFac['FacultyID'];

        $resultEmp = SelectSingleRow("tblFaculty","ID='$facid'","");

        if($resultFac['ID']!=''){

        $empid= $resultEmp['EmployeeID'];

        $response["Emp_id"]=$empid;

         $response["flag"]=1;

         echo json_encode($response);

        }

    }

    else{

        $response["flag"]=0;

            echo "Please enter correct user name password";

         echo json_encode($response);

    } 

    }else{

        $response["flag"]=0;

         echo json_encode($response);

        echo "Please enter both the fields";

    }

  ?>
```

and my login activity

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    int flag;
    int empid;
    String username;
    String password;

    EditText edUsername,edPassword;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray jarray;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    private static String url_faculty_login = "http://10.0.2.2/xyz/login_check.php";
    private static final String TAG_EMPLOYEE = "employee_id";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
    //  setTitleColor(1);

        Intent i=new Intent();


        edUsername=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edUserName);
        edPassword=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edPassword);
        String clear="clear";

    }

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    LoginActivity.this.finish();
    //  LoginActivity.

}

//@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();


    LoginActivity.this.finish();
}
//onClick login.xml Button
    public void signIn(View view) {
        //call to inner class
        if(edUsername!=null && edPassword!=null )
        {
            new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        }
        else 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Both Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        }
    }

    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private static final String Emp_id = "Emp_id";


        public String doInBackground(String... args) {
             username=edUsername.getText().toString();
             password=edPassword.getText().toString();

             List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", password));



            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_faculty_login, "POST", params);
            Log.d("Username n password: ", json.toString());

            try {
                 flag=json.getInt("flag");
                Log.d("flags",""+flag);
            } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(flag==1)
            {           
                try 
                {
                    empid=json.getInt(Emp_id);
                } 
                catch (JSONException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ClassActivity.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                i.putExtra("Emp_id", ""+empid);
                Log.d("Empid",""+empid);

                startActivity(i);
            }
            if(flag==0)
            {
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),InvalidUPLoginActivity.class);

                startActivity(i);
            }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: when log out clear the history

Comment: post only the relevant code. remove the import statements

Comment: called this function on backpressed of next activity
private void launchIntent() {
 //  Log.i("positive button","pressed");
   Intent i=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
  // Log.e("from main menu","calling login");
   startActivity(i); 
   }

Comment: I tried edUsername.setText(""); edPassword.setText("");
 in onPostExecute(); also after setext() 
But Still getting previous records pleassssssss help...

Answer (score 0):

**After**

```
  username=edUsername.getText().toString();
  password=edPassword.getText().toString();

  edUsername.setText("");
  edPassword.setText("");
```